# Segfault passing QString to function

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, qstring

I want to pass G-CODEs to a 3D printer from my Qt app. I have a function that takes a QString and passes it to an external program as an argument:

```
void MainWindow::gcodeRelay( const QString &gcode )
{
    QObject *parent;
    relayProcess= new QProcess(parent);
    QString program = "./gcoderelay/gcoderelay";
    relayProcess->start(program, QStringList() << ui->tcp_server->text() << ui->client_port->text() << gcode );
}
```

But calling the function causes the program to crash with segfault:

```
void MainWindow::on_custom_gcode_clicked()
{
    QString gcode = ui->line_custom_gcode->text();    //SEGFAULT
    gcodeRelay( gcode );
}
```

This works:

```
void MainWindow::on_custom_gcode_clicked()
{
    QString gcode = "G28";                              //WORKS
    gcodeRelay( gcode );
}
```

Interestingly, this does not:

```
void MainWindow::on_custom_gcode_clicked()
{
    QString gcode;
    gcode = "G28";                                  //SEGFAULT
    gcodeRelay( gcode );
}
```

According to debugger the crash occurrs when the new process is *created* (before it's started)

Why does this happen? Also I'm confused as to what is the difference between the last two snippets of code and how could it cause such a problem?

Thank you and I'm just learning so be kind :)

Comment: You have an uninitialized pointer: `QObject *parent;`.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak The last snippet of code also segfaults

Comment: @thuga Shouldn't the example of a working code also fail if that was the case? (Not to mention it shouldn't compile?)

Comment: Of course it will compile. You might get a warning that you have an uninitialized variable, but that's about it. Anyway, it's undefined behavior when you try to use an uninitialized pointer. Sometimes you will get a segfault, but other times you won't.

Comment: @thuga Thank you so much!! That was the problem! :)

Comment: Please do not modify the question when it's answered. An answer belongs **always** only in an answer.